# Metal bracket to hang stringer below joist?

Tags: framing, deck, joists, hanging

I need to hang a stringer (basically another 2x8) right below my deck joist 2x8. Look like this photo

[image]

Can you tell me what kind of hanger / bracket is it in the red circle?

The article is from here

http://www.familyhandyman.com/decks/designs/backyard-decks-build-an-island-deck/view-all

And I was looking at this skew hanger but I don't believe it has ability to allow the 2x8 to sit right below another 2x8:

http://www.lowes.com/pd_29926-166-LSSH15-TZ___?productId=3375802

Comment: If you mean stair stringers, there's probably a better way to go about this. Consider posting a photo or sketch of your actual scenario.

Comment: @isherwood Check out [the article](http://www.familyhandyman.com/decks/designs/backyard-decks-build-an-island-deck/view-all) that the OP mentioned... the step is hanging from the deck... I think this is interesting, but also a bit sketchy.

Comment: I see now. It's basically in inverted cantilever. I don't think that's what the OP is doing, though.

Comment: @isherwood well, I'm not really sure either...he says **"a stringer"**. I edited my answer to at least clarify my own thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpson Strong Tie makes an ["Adjustable Truss Hanger"](http://www.strongtie.com/topflangehangersssl_solidsawnlumberconnectors/tha-thac-thar-l_productgroup_wcc/p/tha.thac.thar.l)  THA-Series.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those are simple L-angle joist hangers. I'm not sure if it's appropriate to use them like that, though... especially if you plan to use the stringer to support something (other than itself).

In other words, the ground-support should be directly supporting the stringer and the joists should be resting on the stringer- unless you will not be using the stringer to support anything (significant)... but then why would you put it there?

edit- After some consideration, I think that this hanging step is interesting. I wouldn't make two steps like that, of course, and I wouldn't skimp on the stringers... the picture shows 7 stringers, each about 4 ft long, for one step/tread; it will be an expensive step, but part of the safety is a measure of how far you fall... maybe 8 to 10 inches.

[image]

Comment: So my deck level is like 12 inches from the ground. I am wondering if using stringer as joists and hang them is a bit overkill or not. Can I just use cheaper method? For example, can I just attach the 2x6 or 2x8 horizontally and bolt them on a 2x4 coming down from top (which is attached to the top joists)?

Comment: @HP. Generally, you don't want to hang loads from the joists, you want to support everything from from the ground (and I just can't recommend otherwise). My first thought would be to build the step like any any other, but since you only need one step, a cheaper option would be to skip the stringers and just use a couple of posts, building the step like a short bench. It wouldn't even need to be attached to the deck, but if you wanted to, you could hide a couple of backets behind or under the step.